# Visual c# relatively dynamic comboboxes

Tags: c#, combobox

I have two related comboboxes, combobox1 populate the items of combobox2. In combobox1 `selectIndexChanged` event I have this code but i have error `Unknown column 'System.Data.DataRowView' in 'where clause'`.

I tried to put this code in the `SelectionChangeCommitted` at first selection, it populate the right items, but my second selection i have error in `comboBox2.Items.Clear();` states `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.` :( what to do.?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql;
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        sql = "SELECT brgyname,idbrgy from barangay where idmun=" + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
        adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        DataTable cbBrgy = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(cbBrgy);
        comboBox2.DataSource = cbBrgy;
        comboBox2.DisplayMember = "brgyname";
        comboBox2.ValueMember = "idbrgy";
    }
}
```

Here's how i populate combobox1

```
   private void cbMun()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT munname,idmun from municipality", conn);
        DataTable cbMun = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(cbMun);
        comboBox1.DataSource = cbMun;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "munname";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "idmun";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just placed my code in `comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted` not in `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` event since `comboBox1.SelectedValue` is still not generated not unless the user committed its changes to the items. Also my `Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set` error from `comboBox2.Items.Clear();` i just deleted this line of code. I still clears and replace my combobox2 items properly. Hmm.. Since i used to clear comboboxes in vb..I wonder.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlString);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    sql = "SELECT brgyname,idbrgy from barangay where idmun=" + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
    adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
    DataTable cbBrgy = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(cbBrgy);
    comboBox2.DataSource = cbBrgy;
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "brgyname";
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "idbrgy";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while cbMun function is filling the combobox it will call combobox selected index change event directly , so to work around this define bool value comboisloading = true and modify your code such like below :

```
    private void cbMun()
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlString);
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT munname,idmun from municipality", conn);
        DataTable cbMun = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(cbMun);
        comboBox1.DataSource = cbMun;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "munname";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "idmun";
        comboisloading = false;
    }
```

---

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboisloading)
            return;

        string sql;
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(sqlString);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sql = "SELECT brgyname,idbrgy from barangay where idmun=" + comboBox1.SelectedValue;
            adapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            DataTable cbBrgy = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(cbBrgy);
            comboBox2.DataSource = cbBrgy;
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "brgyname";
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "idbrgy";
        }
    }
```